# Guess the number in 5 chance using if else in python

Tags: python

I'm working on a simple assignment, where I need to guess the number in five tries without utilizing a while loop. I've written the following code, however, I'm not sure how to continue the loop in this code; any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
number=9
guess_taken=0

if guess_taken < 5:
    number_input = int(input('please guess: '))
    if number_input==number:
        print('correct guess'+number_input)
    elif number_input!=number:
        print('guess again')
        guess_taken = guess_taken+1
```

Comment: Please, don't use bot version specific tags.

Comment: If you can't use a `while` loop, your choices are a `for` loop or a recursive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive function until your condition is met.

```
number=9
guess_taken=0

def guess(guess_taken):
    if guess_taken < 5:
        number_input = int(input('please guess: '))
        if number_input==number:
            print('correct guess: '+ str(number_input))
        elif number_input != number:
                print('guess again: ')
                guess_taken = guess_taken+1

                # call function until condition is met
                guess(guess_taken)  

guess(guess_taken)
```